# Is there a reason to send money home?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

After you get through the tutorial, the courier, Max, will offer to let you send additional money home to Leftheria. Is there any real reason to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it turns out, sending home 90k (not sure about other increments, but I hit the 90k option) will start a side quest chain when you are able to go to Leftheria.

Comment: Apparently it is not possible to send moe than 90k. Also how do you start quest chain? Currier refuses to take more money, but I don't have quest yet. Maybe it is triggered by plot?

Comment: You probably have to go to Leftheria first.